# How to call a function and end the current function

Tags: c, stack

I have a menu program that works by calling each menu page as a function. But if the user selects 'Back' and 'Next' repeatedly the call stack will continue to increase which means I believe the program could theoretically crash.
In this code and in my program once the next menu function is called I would like to delete the current function from the stack since I no longer need it. Is such a thing possible?
Here is some sample code:

```
void menu1()
{
    //Get user input
    if (input == 0) //Go to menu2
        menu2();
    else     //Invalid input try again
        menu1();
}
void menu2()
{
    //Get user input
    if (input == 0) //Do something
    else if (input == 1) //Go back
        menu1();
    else        //Invalid input try again
        menu2();
}
```

As can be seen if the user inputs '0, 1, 0, 1...' then the stack keeps on growing.

Comment: I forgot to mention that there are more than one menu option, so there is a chain of else if statements. So I don't think the function will automatically clean up after itself

Comment: That's why you shouldn't use needless/inappropriate recursion like that. Have a top level function with a simple loop that parses input and calls the appropriate function

Comment: @Bill for clarifications of your question, don't add comments, but instead [edit] the question.

Comment: This is basically a state machine.

Comment: What do you mean by 'delete the current function'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correct, you have N different menu pages and on each of these pages you want to be able to

1. select a specific operation

or

2. goto another menu page

As you correctly noticed there's a problem with your current approach. Your code keep calling either the other menu function or the same menu function (i.e. like recursive calls). That is not the way to write the code. You need to let the current function return before calling the next function. Staying within the same function until you get a specific input can be done using a `while` loop.

A menu system can be implemented in many ways.

Below is a very simple example with 3 menu pages.

The code is in no way the optimal approach. It's intentionally kept very simple in order to show one way to avoid constantly doing recursive calls.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int menu0()
{
    while(1)
    {
        puts("--- Menu 0 ---");
        puts("Enter 0-9 to switch menu");
        puts("Enter a for operation A");
        puts("Enter b for operation B");
        puts("Enter e to exit");

        char input;
        if (scanf(" %c", &input) != 1) exit(1); // Get input
        if (input >= '0' && input <= '9')
        {
            // Go to another menu page
            return input - '0';
        }
        if (input == 'e')
        {
            // Exit program
            return 999;
        }

        if (input == 'a')
        {
            puts("Doing operation A");
        }
        else if (input == 'b')
        {
            puts("Doing operation B");
        }
    }
}

int menu1()
{
    while(1)
    {
        puts("--- Menu 1 ---");
        puts("Enter 0-9 to switch menu");
        puts("Enter a for operation X");
        puts("Enter b for operation Y");
        puts("Enter e to exit");

        char input;
        if (scanf(" %c", &input) != 1) exit(1); // Get input
        if (input >= '0' && input <= '9')
        {
            // Go to another menu page
            return input - '0';
        }
        if (input == 'e')
        {
            // Exit program
            return 999;
        }

        if (input == 'a')
        {
            puts("Doing operation X");
        }
        else if (input == 'b')
        {
            puts("Doing operation Y");
        }
    }
}

int menu2()
{
    while(1)
    {
        puts("--- Menu 2 ---");
        puts("Enter 0-9 to switch menu");
        puts("Enter a for operation S");
        puts("Enter b for operation T");
        puts("Enter e to exit");

        char input;
        if (scanf(" %c", &input) != 1) exit(1); // Get input
        if (input >= '0' && input <= '9')
        {
            // Go to another menu page
            return input - '0';
        }
        if (input == 'e')
        {
            // Exit program
            return 999;
        }

        if (input == 'a')
        {
            puts("Doing operation S");
        }
        else if (input == 'b')
        {
            puts("Doing operation T");
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    int next = 0;  // Start in menu0
    while(1)
    {
        if (next == 0)
        {
            next = menu0();
        }
        else if (next == 1)
        {
            next = menu1();
        }
        else if (next == 2)
        {
            next = menu2();
        }
        else if (next == 999)
        {
            break;  // End program
        }
        else
        {
            next = 0;  // Unknow menu selected so go to menu0
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Each menu-page stays in a loop (a `while`) until the input is 0, 1, .. , 9 in which case the function returns the number so that `main` can call the corresponding menu-page.

Further, each menu-page accepts inputs like a, b to perform a specific operation and e for exit.

Answer (score 2):

Function calls are not the correct way to implement this kind of control flow. You need **[State Machines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine)**.

Instead of functions, you need to think of *states*, which represents each menu. Then you need to define actions/tasks you need to do when arriving to or leaving a state. Your program needs to keep track of the state it's currently in.

Answer (score 1):

Why can't you put your code into a loop and just repeat input? This should work unless I'm missing something regarding your question...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
void menu1(){
    printf("You chose menu1\n");
}
void menu2(){
    printf("You chose menu2\n");
}
int main(){
    long linput = 0;
    
    do{
        char cinput[3] = {0};
        printf("Choose a menu (1) or (2) or 0 to exit:");
        fgets(cinput, sizeof(cinput), stdin);

        linput = strtol(cinput, NULL, 10);
        switch (linput) {
            case 1:
                menu1();
                break;
            case 2:
                menu2();
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }while(linput!=0);
           
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Do not integrate the user choice intake and jumping to corresponding function into each function body. Refactor your code for:

- Asking the user for input
- Call a corresponding function
- Return to the caller (or `main()`), and ask for another input.
- Call a corresponding function

and continue as needed, or end the flow. This way, for every choice a function will be called every time, and returned.